# Checking my understanding of the bias-variance tradeoff

Tags: variance, bias

Hello fellow DS aficionados, I'm trying to clarify some confusing feedback I got from a homework problem.

We were told to recreate the bias-variance tradeoff graph using the first graph below as an example (with my recreation just below that).

The grading TA commented that "[my] test error should be lowest at 35 degrees of freedom." However, I've always been told that test error at higher DFs should begin to rise as overfitting is introduced which makes sense to me. The exemplar graph shows that and that's how I've always understood it (I have a decent background in DS so I don't feel like I could have gotten this far not understanding that).

So, what am I missing? Why did the TA say that my test errors should be lowest at the highest DF?

[image: this graph]. [image]

Comment: You sure the TA didn't just make a mistake and actually have meant to say that the **train** error should be lowest at 35 DOF? It seems like an easy mistake to make and would actually make sense.

Comment: I asked him to clarify, and he's adamant that the test error should have been the lowest at that point. Either way, my train error is lowest at 35 but he still counted the whole thing incorrect.